# Can't perform retweet or like using Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to perform some actions using Twitter API, for some reason I can't use retweet or like.

I authenticate using `consumer_key`, `consumer_key_secret`, and user's `token`, `token_secret`.
I can perform other actions (like reply, tweet, quote) but only retweet and like get me the following error:

> When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

Am I using the wrong authentication method?
code used : https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Manage-Retweets/retweet_a_tweet.py

```js
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import os
import json

# In your terminal please set your environment variables by running the following lines of code.
# export 'CONSUMER_KEY'='<your_consumer_key>'
# export 'CONSUMER_SECRET'='<your_consumer_secret>'

consumer_key = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_KEY")
consumer_secret = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_SECRET")


# Be sure to replace your-user-id with your own user ID or one of an authenticating user
# You can find a user ID by using the user lookup endpoint
id = "your-user-id"

# You can replace the given Tweet ID with your the Tweet ID you want to Retweet
# You can find a Tweet ID by using the Tweet lookup endpoint
payload = {"tweet_id": "1412865600439738368"}

# Get request token
request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret)

try:
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
except ValueError:
    print(
        "There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered."
    )

resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token")
resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get("oauth_token_secret")
print("Got OAuth token: %s" % resource_owner_key)

# Get authorization
base_authorization_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
print("Please go here and authorize: %s" % authorization_url)
verifier = input("Paste the PIN here: ")

# Get the access token
access_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
    resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
    verifier=verifier,
)
oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url)

access_token = oauth_tokens["oauth_token"]
access_token_secret = oauth_tokens["oauth_token_secret"]

# Make the request
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
)

# Making the request
response = oauth.post(
    "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/{}/retweets".format(id), json=payload
)

if response.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception(
        "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
    )

print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

# Saving the response as JSON
json_response = response.json()
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.